# Getting an “is not a block special device.” error when trying to mount an 8TB disk in CentOS 7.6

Tags: hard-drive, centos, ext4

I'm trying to format and mount a 8TB external as an ext4 and it doesn't seem to work right. The drive is a Seagate 8TB expansion desktop drive. Model number is [STEB8000402](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/expansion-desk-8tbDS1843-8-1810GB-en_GB.pdf).

I can create my partition using gdisk:

```
sdc               8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdc1            8:33   0   7.3T  0 part
```

But when I create the filesystem I get a weird error that says: “/dev/sdc1 is not a block special device.” however it seems to complete:

```
# mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdc1 is not a block special device.
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Discarding device blocks: done
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
246512 inodes, 984801 blocks
49240 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=1008730112
31 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
7952 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Afterwards though, when mounting it doesn't seem to work and it mounts `/dev/loop0` instead? I'm not even sure what that is and the filesystem is the wrong size.

```
/dev/loop0               4.0G   16M  3.7G   1% /mnt/test
```

I was reading apparently this is some new type of drive with sectors not in the normal place? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the partitioning method  GPT? MBR eont work for large disks.

Comment: Try to umount before running mke2fs, or use `-F`.

Comment: it is set to gpt, I mount after mke2fs

Comment: i formatted the drive as NTFS in windows, just to make sure the partition is right, but mounting the drive still only shows up as 3.8G when running df-h

Comment: Please edit your question to add specifics such as what version of CentOS you are on and what the exact brand, make and model of the drive is. Also, [did you read this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/fdisk-unable-to-create-partition-greater-2tb.html) on drives not showing correct sizes past 2TB? While you are showing 4TB it seems like it might be helpful.

Comment: i had followed that guide but it didn't help, stuck in the same step. the drive is a seagate 8tb expansion desktop drive. specifically the STEB8000402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device might already have been partitioned and have a file system.
You may need to first get rid of everything.

Use `fdisk` on the disk itself, `/dev/sdc` rather than on the partition
`/dev/sdc1`:

```
sudo fdisk -cu /dev/sdc
```

If you have any existing partitions, first delete them using the command `d`,
and finally `w` to write the partition table and exit.

Reissue `fdisk -cu /dev/sdc` and use `n` to create a new partition with
maximum size and `w` again.

Check that everything is correct using `fdisk -lu /dev/sdc`.

You may finally format the new partition:

```
sudo mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

Or alternatively:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: I got it working thank you! the -cu switches didn't work for fdisk but i didn't need them it turned out. the mkfs command worked fine.

Comment: If you "followed harrymc instructions and now everything is working", shouldn't I be getting some credit?

Comment: indeed, but i can only pick 1 answer. although your instructions helped i already knew them. the issue was the fact i had a file instead of a partition. i wish i could pick both, as the issue isn't complete with just one post. Hopefully anyone else that comes across this can piece it together.

Comment: You may actually pick 2 answers: One for acceptance and one for the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is you had created a regular file there somehow (or maybe a symlink to such file). Check it. If it was a block device then in the output of

```
ls -l /dev/sdc1
```

the first letter would be `b`; additionally

```
file /dev/sdc1
```

would say `block special`. If this is not the case, investigate what the object really is. It probably shouldn't be there in the first place. Note mounting a regular file uses a loop device, this fits your case.

If the object is indeed a regular file or a symlink, `umount` it, then remove (`rm`) or move (`mv`) it out of the way. Keep in mind `mke2fs` operated on the file, so if you already put any important data in the filesystem, it's in the file, not in the partition.

To recreate a proper `/dev/sdc1` as a block device, invoke `sudo partprobe`. This assumes there is no problem with `/dev/sdc` and its partition table. You should also invoke `mke2fs` again because the partition wasn't even touched by your previous `mke2fs`.

---

A plausible cause of having a regular file there is writing an image file to `/dev/sdc1` without making sure the target exists (normally as a block device). Such operation on an *nonexistent* target creates a regular file.

If the problem reappears (like after reboot, after connecting the external drive again) it means something recreates the file. This may be due to some poorly written script that assumes `/dev/sdc1` always exists. Be warned such script can overwrite your actual partition when the drive is connected. Hopefully there is no script at all and the whole problem is because of one-time mishap as described above.

Comment: you where right apparently i created a file instead of a partition somehow. I removed it and followed harrymc instructions and now everything is working. thanks to you both!