# Is /dev/sda a file or a directory?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive

I want to format a flash drive as exFAT, but I want to make sure that I get the device right.  So, I decided to check the contents of `/dev/sda`, where I believe the flash drive is.  However, when I tried to `cd` into it, it gave me an error saying that it wasn't a directory.  So I thought "Oh, it's a file that contains all the information about the contents of the drive."  Therefore, I tried to use Vim on it.  But that gave me an error saying that it wasn't a file!

Is /dev/sda a file or a directory?  (Also, is there a better way to make sure that I'm using the correct device?)

Comment: Neither; It's a device.

Comment: Thanks, @KamilMaciorowski!  I used `lsblk` to determine that, yes, my flash drive is indeed located at /dev/sda.

Comment: Actually it is a file. Everything is a file.

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/sda` is formally a file because [in Unix/Linux almost everything is a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). Normally it's a [block special file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60034/108618) associated with a block device. You can call `/dev/sda` a "device node". By "normally" I mean "by convention", because you can create `/dev/sda` as any other file type if you wish; still every user that has a clue will expect it to be a block special file.

A relatively common scenario where `/dev/sdX` turns out to be a regular file is after a user wrote something to this path without making sure it existed as a special file in the first place. Writing to a nonexistent path can create a regular file. Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1401537/432690).

What Vim meant was your `/dev/sda` is not a regular file; `cd` told you it's not a directory. It's most likely a block special device as it should be. You can confirm this by `ls -l` or `file`. Example:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Oct 28 15:35 /dev/sda
$ # That 'b' in front indicates a block special file.
$
$ file /dev/sda
/dev/sda: block special (8/0)
$
```

---

> is there a better way to make sure that I'm using the correct device?

`lsblk`. Also see [how to detect whether a hard drive is external USB or internal](https://superuser.com/q/1493076/432690).

---

You cannot `cd` to `/dev/sda` to see its content. The device may contain one or more filesystems but to browse a filesystem you need to mount it first. Example:

```
mount /dev/sda /mnt
# then browse /mnt/
```

This exact command will make sense if there's a filesystem on the entire device. Usually there is a partition table; then filesystems reside in partitions referred to and mounted via `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` etc. Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1181320/432690).

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sda is a code name for a device. You can not browse these codenames. You can only mount them to a real folder (e.g. /media/my-usb) and then browse the mounted folder.